# Muliple Excel sheet creation using vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

i want to generate "n" number of excel sheets , where "n" is a value coming from database i.e
"select count( column_name) from table_name" will give me "n"
for it n=5 its mean in book1 i need 5 sheets

i am using following code to generate excel sheet1

```
     spreadsheet = CreateObject("Excel.application")
     spreadsheet.Visible = True
     book1 = spreadsheet.Workbooks.Add()
     sheet1 = book1.Worksheets("sheet1")
```

thanks

Comment: Is this vb.net or VBA? They are **not** the same.  Note that in either method, this does not actually *generate* sheet1. a workbook is *always* created with at least one sheet.  You just need to add sheets, which should be the Worksheets.Add method.  Use that in a loop `For i = 2 to n...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Sheets.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839847(v=office.15).aspx) Method

```
Sub GenerateSheets()
n = 5
For i = 1 To n
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets is a collection of worksheet objects, so using the `.add(New Worksheet)` metthod in a for loop should work.

```
For I = 1 To n-1 ' n-1 because it automatically starts with one worksheet
    book1.Worksheets.Add(New Worksheet)
Next
```